# c++ logical alternative operator

Tags: c++, logical-operators, operator-precedence

During work over a simple project I have found situation that I don't fully understand. Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool test(int k)
{
    cout << "start " << k << endl;

    bool result; // it is important that result's value is opposite to initial value of recheck in main()
    result = false;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    bool recheck;
    recheck = true;
    for (int i = 2; i > -1; i--)
    {
      recheck = (recheck || test(i));   // (1)
      cout << i << " ???" <<endl;
    }
    cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    recheck = true;
    for (int i = 2; i > -1; i--)
    {
        recheck = (test(i) || recheck);  //different order that in (1)
        cout << i << "???" <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It returns completely different results from `for` loops:

```
2 ???
1 ???
0 ???
----------------------------

start 2
2???
start 1
1???
start 0
0???
```

It seems that it first one `test(int k)` is not even invoked. I suspect it has something to do with `||` operator. Could anybody explain such a behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The built-in `||` short-circuits:  if the left operand is `true`, the right operand is not evaluated (it doesn't matter what the value of the right operand is, because the value of the `||` expression is guaranteed to be `true` in this case).

<sup>For completeness, but not particularly relevant to the question:  In c++, the `||` operator is overloadable, just as many other operators are.  If an overload is used, short circuiting does not take place.</sup>

Comment: You guys are too fast on this stuff.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to disable it (just in case:) )- a compiler flag or sth?

Comment: No, this can't be disabled.  It's a fundamental feature of the language.  However, if both operands are already of type `bool`, and you are going to store the result in a `bool` (or otherwise convert the result to `bool`) use the `|` operator.  It does not short-circuit.  (Its semantics are different, but if both operands are of type `bool` and the result is used as a `bool`, it has the same behavior as the `||` operator, sans short-circuiting.)

Answer (score 1):

The boolean operators `||` and `&&` will *short-circuit* when one of the operands - evaluating from left-to-right - can determine the result of the expression, without reference to the remaining operands.

In the case of `||`, this means that if the first operand is `true`, the remaining operands aren't evaluated, because the result of the entire expression will always be `true`.

In the first loop, the variable `recheck` - that is local to `main` - is always `true`, and so the function call `test` never needs to be evaluated: it is skipped, and you see no output.

In the second loop, the `test` function call is evaluated first, and it's result can only be determined after calling the function, so the function is called on each iteration, and you see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment says:

> it is important that result's value is opposite to initial value of recheck in main()

Your `test()` function currently can't see the value of `recheck`, which is local to `main()`.

Assuming your comment reflects your intent, you need to pass `recheck` as a parameter to `test()`; you can then use the unary `!` operator, something like:

```
result = ! recheck;
```

And of course you need to fix the logic in `main()` so that `test()` is called when you need it to be.

Your requirements aren't clear enough for me to comment further.

Answer (score 0):

Others have addressed the specific issue that you have raised.  Just a note to say that beware of using multiple question marks in a row.  Trigraph sequences start with two '??' characters and the third character after two question marks is interpreted differently.